# jQuery - Can I animate css properties? Background-image particularly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, background-image

I know I can fade in and out divs and elements, but can I animate properties as well?
I thought about this just now when changing background-image property of a certain div. And thought it'd be cool if the background image was faded in as well ;)

Here's the code I'm using to replace background image. But can it be animated?

```
var originalBG = $('#wrapper').css('background-image');
$('.bggallery_images img').hover(function () {
    var newBG = "url('" + $(this).attr('src');

    $('#wrapper').css('background-image', newBG);
}, function () {
    $('#wrapper').css('background-image', originalBG);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has the [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method that does exactly that.

Check out the examples in the manual, they should show you everything you need.

Comment: Just checked it out. But it doesn't seem like it recognize background-image. Background seems to work though. Would you mind having a peek at my OP, updated with some code.

Comment: @Kenny mmm, overread that part, I understood `background-color`. `background-image` is not going to work, that is not fadable in CSS and jQuery can't add that functionality. You'd have to change the `opacity` of the element containing the background image, or introduce a new element for that.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I figured. I'd have to apply a new set of wrapper div and apply the new background image onto that. Then fade the old one away.

Answer (score 1):

[JQuery UI](http://www.jqueryui.com) is a plug in that extends the animation function to animate color if that's what you're looking to do with the background.  Basically if JQuery doesn't do it, there's most likely a library that extends it to have that functionality.